# Is it possible to have a Business Event call Custom Code in Acumatica?

Tags: c#, acumatica

When my user adds an appointment, he wants to have 2 things happen:

1. Send an acknowledgement of the appointment to the customer's cell phone, with information about the appointment
2. 24 hours before the appointment, to have a reminder sent out

The main issue is that the event screen displays dates as UTC. This, of course, confuses the customer. So, I need to change the date and format the text message via code.

When I first did this, there was no way to call a custom method from a business event -- so I actually send the message up to Twilio, catch that with a Webhook that sends it into my custom DLL. That massages the message, making everything look right, and then sends it back through Twilio to the customer.

But this is costly (2 messages sent and 1 received for every event) and needlessly complicated. I want to simplify it now, because I have been told there is added functionality in Business events now that allows a call out into custom code. Is this true?

I was told that this would be available starting in 2020 R2. I am looking for it in the docs and training classes, but I can't see anywhere that this is possible.

How do I call custom code from a business event? Can I set up a subscriber that is in a custom DLL?

Is there something that describes this process somewhere? Or did this never make it into the product?

Comment: You can setup an import scenario that executes a custom action. This import scenario can then be setup as a subscriber in your business events.

Comment: @Rick I didn't know I could do that in an import scenario. Is there documentation on that somewhere you can point me to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to implement a custom Business Event subscriber (coded in your own dll), I know that is possible in 2021 R1.

There are basic instructions in the [Release Notes for Developers](https://acumatica-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/builds/21.1/ReleaseNotes/AcumaticaERP_2021R1_ReleaseNotes_for_Developers.pdf) starting on page 15.

The upshot is you need to reference the `PX.BusinessProcess.dll` and implement the `PX.BusinessProcess.Subscribers.ActionHandlers.IEventAction` interface and either of the `PX.BusinessProcess.Subscribers.Factories.IBPSubscriberActionHandlerFactory` or `PX.BusinessProcess.Subscribers.Factories.IBPSubscriberActionHandlerFactoryWithCreateAction` interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example blog from crestwood to use business events to create an import scenario: https://www.crestwood.com/2020/05/19/using-business-events-to-create-transactions-employee-birthday-checks/

The gist of it would be to create the generic inquiry to monitor. Next, you would create a business event that ties to the generic inquiry. Go under subscribers, select Create New Subscriber, and then name it. It will load the import scenario, and attach the provider to the event.

For provider object in the business event, you can fill from Results or Previous Results.

This is based on the aborted shipments in sales demo, but it shows my custom action after matching shipment number.

[image]

once saved, you can see your business event shows up as a subscriber:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the code I was looking for I **was** in the Acumatica Help files, as TTook suggested. The reason I am publishing more on this is that the answer in help files aren't very reliable (sometimes) down the road, and I wanted a complete version of the code here -- including all of the using/includes. So, here it is:

This creates an event and a subscriber to respond to a Business Event. The code shows writing the screen data to a text file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.BusinessProcess.Subscribers.ActionHandlers;
using PX.BusinessProcess.Subscribers.Factories;
using PX.BusinessProcess.Event;
using PX.BusinessProcess.DAC;
using PX.BusinessProcess.UI;
using System.Threading;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Common;
using PX.SM;
using System.IO;
using PX.Data.Wiki.Parser;
using PX.PushNotifications;

namespace CustomSubscriber
{
    //The custom subscriber that the system executes once the business event 
    //has occurred
    public class CustomSMSEventAction : IEventAction
    {
        //The GUID that identifies a subscriber
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        //The name of the subscriber of the custom type
        public string Name { get; protected set; }

        //The notification template
        private readonly Notification _notificationTemplate;

        //The method that writes the body of the notification to a text file 
        //once the business event has occurred
        public void Process(MatchedRow[] eventRows, CancellationToken cancellation)
        {
            using (StreamWriter file =
              new StreamWriter(@"C:\tmp\EventRows.txt"))
            {
                var graph = PXGenericInqGrph.CreateInstance(
                  _notificationTemplate.ScreenID);
                var parameters = @eventRows.Select(
                  r => Tuple.Create<IDictionary<string, object>,
                  IDictionary<string, object>>(
                    r.NewRow?.ToDictionary(c => c.Key.FieldName, c => c.Value),
                    r.OldRow?.ToDictionary(c => c.Key.FieldName,
                      c => (c.Value as ValueWithInternal)?.ExternalValue ??
                        c.Value))).ToArray();
                var body = PXTemplateContentParser.ScriptInstance.Process(
                  _notificationTemplate.Body, parameters, graph, null);
                file.WriteLine(body);
            }
        }

        //The CustomEventAction constructor
        public CustomSMSEventAction(Guid id, Notification notification)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = notification.Name;
            _notificationTemplate = notification;
        }
    }

    //The class that creates and executes the custom subscriber
    class CustomSubscriberHandlerFactory :
      IBPSubscriberActionHandlerFactoryWithCreateAction
    {
        //The method that creates a subscriber with the specified ID
        public IEventAction CreateActionHandler(Guid handlerId,
          bool stopOnError, IEventDefinitionsProvider eventDefinitionsProvider)
        {
            var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PXGraph>();
            Notification notification = PXSelect<Notification,
              Where<Notification.noteID,
              Equal<Required<Notification.noteID>>>>
                .Select(graph, handlerId).AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault();

            return new CustomSMSEventAction(handlerId, notification);
        }

        //The method that retrieves the list of subscribers of the custom type
        public IEnumerable<BPHandler> GetHandlers(PXGraph graph)
        {
            return PXSelect<Notification, Where<Notification.screenID,
              Equal<Current<BPEvent.screenID>>,
              Or<Current<BPEvent.screenID>, IsNull>>>
                .Select(graph).FirstTableItems.Where(c => c != null)
                .Select(c => new BPHandler
                {
                    Id = c.NoteID,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Type = LocalizableMessages.CustomNotification
                });
        }

        //The method that performs redirection to the subscriber
        public void RedirectToHandler(Guid? handlerId)
        {
            var notificationMaint =
              PXGraph.CreateInstance<SMNotificationMaint>();
            notificationMaint.Message.Current =
              notificationMaint.Notifications.
                Search<Notification.noteID>(handlerId);
            PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(notificationMaint,
              PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.New);
        }

        //A string identifier of the subscriber type that is 
        //exactly four characters long
        public string Type
        {
            get { return "CTTP"; }
        }

        //A string label of the subscriber type
        public string TypeName
        {
            get { return LocalizableMessages.CustomNotification; }
        }

        //A string identifier of the action that creates 
        //a subscriber of the custom type
        public string CreateActionName
        {
            get { return "NewCustomNotification"; }
        }

        //A string label of the button that creates 
        //a subscriber of the custom type
        public string CreateActionLabel
        {
            get { return LocalizableMessages.CreateCustomNotification; }
        }

        //The delegate for the action that creates 
        //a subscriber of the custom type
        public Tuple<PXButtonDelegate, PXEventSubscriberAttribute[]>
          getCreateActionDelegate(BusinessProcessEventMaint maintGraph)
        {
            PXButtonDelegate handler = (PXAdapter adapter) =>
            {
                if (maintGraph.Events?.Current?.ScreenID == null)
                    return adapter.Get();

                var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SMNotificationMaint>();
                var cache = graph.Caches<Notification>();
                var notification = (Notification)cache.CreateInstance();
                var row = cache.InitNewRow(notification);
                row.ScreenID = maintGraph.Events.Current.ScreenID;
                cache.Insert(row);

                var subscriber = new BPEventSubscriber();
                var subscriberRow =
                  maintGraph.Subscribers.Cache.InitNewRow(subscriber);
                subscriberRow.Type = Type;
                subscriberRow.HandlerID = row.NoteID;
                graph.Caches[typeof(BPEventSubscriber)].Insert(subscriberRow);

                PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(graph,
                  PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.NewWindow);
                return adapter.Get();
            };
            return Tuple.Create(handler,
                new PXEventSubscriberAttribute[]
                    {new PXButtonAttribute {
                      OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Refresh}});
        }
    }

    //Localizable messages
    [PXLocalizable]
    public static class LocalizableMessages
    {
        public const string CustomNotification = "Custom SMS Notification";
        public const string CreateCustomNotification = "Custom SMS Notification";
    }
}
```